# % of Unique Values by Group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, unique

I want to create the below column `Stories_%` that categorizes unique value %'s.

```
    SubID   Stories   Stories_%
0   102F2   2         1 (20%), 2 (80%)
1   102F2   2         1 (20%), 2 (80%)
2   102F2   2         1 (20%), 2 (80%)
3   102F2   2         1 (20%), 2 (80%)
4   102F2   1         1 (20%), 2 (80%)
5   132F2   2         1 (60%), 2 (40%)
6   132F2   1         1 (60%), 2 (40%)
7   132F2   1         1 (60%), 2 (40%)
8   132F2   2         1 (60%), 2 (40%)
9   132F2   1         1 (60%), 2 (40%)
```

I would drop the duplicates and drop `Stories` so the final table would look like this:

```
    SubID   Stories_%
0   102F2   1 (20%), 2 (80%)
1   132F2   1 (60%), 2 (40%)
```

I started by creating a list with all of the unique values (below):

```
unique_stories = df.groupby(["SubID"])['Stories'].unique().astype(int)
unique_stories
```

```
SubID
001C5        ['2']
001C6        ['2']
002I2        ['2']
004C6        ['2']
005L2        ['2']
           ...    
709E1    ['1' '2']
725E1    ['2' '1']
730E1    ['2' '1']
```

The issue I'm having is getting the %s for each unique count.

I've tried...

```
df.groupby(['SubID'])['Stories'].count()
```

...but this only creates a total count rather than a count of each unique value within that category.

I've researched a number of posts but can only turn up total counts, nunique counts, and count of unique values over the entire column, not by group etc.

Is there a method for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:** You can use `groupby` + `value_counts`:

```
s = df.groupby('SubID')['Stories']\
      .value_counts(normalize=True, sort=False).map('{:.0%}'.format)

(s.index.get_level_values(1).astype(str) + ' (' + s + ')')\
   .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join).reset_index(name='Stories %')
```

**Method 2:** Or you can use `Counter` from `collections`:

```
def normalize():
    d = {}
    for i, g in df.groupby('SubID'):
        c = Counter(g['Stories'])
        d[i] = ', '.join(f'{k} ({v / sum(c.values()):.0%})'
                         for k, v in c.items())
    return d

pd.Series(normalize(), name='Stories %').rename('SubID').reset_index()
```

---

```
   SubID        Stories %
0  102F2  1 (20%),2 (80%)
1  132F2  1 (60%),2 (40%)
```

Comment: Thanks! Using **Method 1**, how do I assign the resulting column ```Stories_%``` as a column in the original **df**

Comment: @Tickets2Moontown Try ``map`  like `df['Stories %'] = df['SubID'].map((s.index.get_level_values(1).astype(str) + ' (' + s + ')').groupby(level=0).agg(','.join))`

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with a slightly different format that stores the same information but, leverages a MultiIndex (which will make future manipulations and calculations simpler) then we can get this with `gropuby` + `size` and then `sum`.

```
s = df.groupby(['SubID', 'Stories']).size()
s = s/s.sum(level=0)  # Divide by the total number within each `'SubID'`
```

---

```
SubID  Stories
102F2  1          0.2
       2          0.8
132F2  1          0.6
       2          0.4
dtype: float64
```